# npm install: 'bower install' exited with error code 1

Tags: node.js, powershell, npm, bower

I want to programm widgets for **XBee ZigBee Cloud Kit**.

To do it, I need first to set up everything.
I'm using this [guide](https://github.com/digidotcom/xbeezigbeecloudkit).

After failing repeatedly the automated setup I started the **Manual setup**. I did install the **Requirements**. So everything so far went good until the last point: `npm install`. I'm getting the following error `bower install' exited with error code 1`. I'm not sure what to do, I'm not used to PowerShell or any other shell.
After failing the installing I get this errors:

> bower justgauge#*                        ECMDERR Failed to
>   execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.c
>   om/oscarcv/justgage.git", exit code of #128 fatal: remote error:
>   Repository not found.
>
> Additional error details: fatal: remote error:   Repository
>   not found.
>
> 'bower install' exited with error code 1
>
> npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601 npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "i nstall"
>
> npm ERR! node v0.12.4
>
> npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! xbee-zigbee-cloud-kit@1.0.0 postinstall: `node postinstall.js`
>
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Failed at the xbee-zigbee-cloud-kit@1.0.0 postinstall script 'node postinstall.js'.
>
> npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the xbee-zigbee-cloud-kit package,
>
> npm ERR! not with npm itself. npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
>
> npm ERR!     node postinstall.js npm ERR!
>   You can get their info via:
>
> npm ERR!     npm owner ls xbee-zigbee-cloud-kit
>
> npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>
> npm ERR! C:\Users\steim\Desktop\XBeeZigBeeCloudKit-master\npm-debug.log

*"This is most likely a problem with the xbee-zigbee-cloud-kit package"*

If this is true, in that case I don't know what to do, because I work with this package.

This is the [npm-debug.log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2vwdagmwktd5hky/npm-debug.log?dl=0). (Sorry I can't post the whole log, too many characters).

I'm using a company laptop:

- Latitude D820
- Windows 7 32 Bit
- Windows PowerShell with Administration

I'm grateful for any kind of help. I'm getting headache trying to figure it out.

Comment: The `git://github.com/oscarcv/justgage.git` repository doesn't exist. I'm not sure where `bower` is getting that from but it needs to be updated to use a repository that does exist.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I wrote `oscarcv` at `git://github.com/oscarcv/justgage.git` asking whether he deleted the data. If this helps, I will put as an answer :)

Comment: Can I change the link in `bower`?
For example instead for `git://github.com/oscarcv/justgage.git` I would try to use `git://https://github.com/toorshia/justgage.git`. I'm not even sure if it could work like this.

Comment: Like I said I'm not sure where bower/npm is getting that link from. You might be able to just update the package list (it might already have been fixed upstream somewhere). Otherwise you can try to find that link in the local config somewhere and replace it. Asking in an npm/bower venue might get you more luck (and/or asking the xbee-zigbee-cloud-kit authors).

Comment: @EtanReisner Thanks for the hint before. I could solve the issue with the guide from [Oscar Costoya](https://github.com/oscarcv).

This is what I did:
1) deleting in `bower.json` `justgage`
2) in PowerShell: `bower install justgage-official`
3) in PowerShell: `bower update`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve it. And can now run the app now localy.

I did this steps to solve the issue:

1. Deleting `justgage` in `bower.json` file.
2. Using commandline: `bower install justgage-official`
3. Using commandline: `bower update`

The only problem is actually I can't start with `foreman start` (but it's another issue), instead I use `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:5000`. After that in browser: `http://localhost:5000`

Thanks *Etan Reisner* for the hint and thanks *Oscar Costoya* for guiding me.